# awk commands using array

Tags: awk

```
Month Sales
January 20
February 30
March 43
February 34
January 12
June 89
May 97
June 60
July 23
August 13
August 45
October 56
October 45
November 34
```

> Write an `awk` script to find the months with no sales.

Do we need to have an array containing the names of all the months and do we have to check it with `array[$1]`? I tried that but I keep messing up the syntax.

```bsh
echo 'January 
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December' | 
awk '
BEGIN{ flag=0;}
{arr[month++]=$0}
{ 
    sales[$1]+=$2;
}
END
{
    for(month in arr)
    {
        if(month in sales)
            flag=1;

        if(flag==0) 
            print month;
    }
}'
```

This is what I've tried so far. I keep getting an error saying:

```
awk: cmd. line:8: END blocks must have an action part
```

Comment: maybe `awk  '$2==0' inputfileName`? or `awk  'NF==1' inputfileName`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Please show us your efforts. There seem to me to be at least 2 ways to approach it (1) create an array indexed by months in a `BEGIN` block, assign values to the elements, then iterate over the array in an `END` block and print any whose value is zero (2) create the array on the fly, then iterate over all the months in an `END` block and print any missing indices.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I can see where you're going with this - but it can be simplified quite a lot

- pipe in the names of the 12 months via standard input and use them as indices of an array
- read the file of monthly sales, deleting each month as we see it
- print whatever months remain at the end

The trick is to use `-` as a special filename to tell awk which order to read the standard input and the file, and `NR==FNR` as a test for whether we are reading `stdin`:

```
printf '%s\n' January February March April May \
    June July August September October November December | awk '
      NR==FNR {sales[$1]; next} {delete sales[$1]} END {for(m in sales) print m}
    ' - sales.txt
December
September
April
```

Note that you don't need to assign values to the array elements - just assigning indices is sufficient to define the array.

Alternatively, you could define the array in a `BEGIN` block:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    sales["January"]; sales["February"]; sales["March"]; 
    sales["April"]; sales["May"]; sales["June"]; 
    sales["July"]; sales["August"]; sales["September"]; 
    sales["October"]; sales["November"]; sales["December"];
  } 
  {delete sales[$1]}
  END {
    for(m in sales) print m
  }' sales.txt
```

---

A couple of alternative KISS approaches:

(1) create an array indexed by months in a `BEGIN` block, assign values to the elements, then iterate over the array in an `END` block and print any whose value is zero

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    sales["January"]; sales["February"]; sales["March"]; 
    sales["April"]; sales["May"]; sales["June"]; 
    sales["July"]; sales["August"]; sales["September"]; 
    sales["October"]; sales["November"]; sales["December"];
  } 
  NR > 1 {
    sales[$1] += $2;
  }
  END {
    for (m in sales) {
      if (sales[m] == 0) print m;
    }
  }
' sales.txt
```

or (2) create the array on the fly from the `sales.txt` file, then iterate over all the months in an `END` block and print any missing indices

```
awk '
  NR > 1 {
    sales[$1] += $2
  } 
  END {
    n = split("January February March April May June July August September October November December", months); 
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
      if (!(months[i] in sales)) print months[i]
    }
  }
' sales.txt
```